# PHP Set value inside JSON

Tags: php, json

I know it's simple but...
I have a json like this:

```
$json = { "Password" : $password,
          "Contact": {
                       "CustomIdOrder": ""
                     };
```

I must change with PHP the value inside "CustomIdOrder". How can i do this?

Comment: *"I know it's simple but... I have a json like this:"* -- It is simple **if** you have a JSON: [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), change the value, [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) if needed. The code you posted is not PHP and no JSON is present.

Comment: i need those "change the value"

Comment: Here is explained how to [change the value](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

Answer (score 3):

as @axiac said use json_decode() and json_enocde()

```
$json = json_decode($json ,true);  
$json ["Contact"]["CustomIdOrder"]="NEW VALUE";   
$json = json_encode($json);
echo $json ;
```

please make sure it is a valid json value your json value is not valid right now.